# How do I delete somebody elses message? Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a `say` command where the bot deletes the message above it instantly? How would I find and delete the message above it. Here is my current code.

```
if (message.content.includes(prefix + 'say')){
   if (!args[1]){
     return message.channel.send('What should I say?')
   }
   message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(" "))
 }
```

All I need is to find and delete the message above it instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You would find and delete the message with the `message.delete`.
You should put `message.delete` after  `message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(" "))`.